# Dynamic (down)casting in Scala

Tags: arrays, scala, types, casting

I'm currently trying to figure out the depths of Scala's type system and Scala reflection.
I have the following example code (my real code is more complex and makes more sense, but boils down to this):

```
abstract class Node
class Foo extends Node
case class ArrayFoo(var subs : Array[Foo]) extends Foo
case class IntFoo(i : Integer) extends Foo

object Main {
  def DoSomething(node : AnyRef) : AnyRef = { // Fix this function?
    // do some stuff
    node
  }

  def SetArrayWithReflection(n : Node, a : AnyRef) = {
    if (a.isInstanceOf[Array[AnyRef]]) {
      val arrayA = a.asInstanceOf[Array[AnyRef]].map(f => DoSomething(f)) // FIX this call?
      val getter = n.getClass.getMethods.find(p => p.getName == "subs")
      val setter = n.getClass.getMethods.find(p => p.getName == "subs_$eq")
      if (setter == None) println("Method not found!") else {
        println(f"would need to downcast from ${arrayA.getClass.getComponentType} to ${getter.get.getReturnType.getComponentType}")
        setter.get.invoke(n, arrayA) // Error happens here
      }
    }
  }

  def main(args : Array[String]) : Unit = {
    val my = ArrayFoo(Array(IntFoo(1), IntFoo(2), IntFoo(3)))
    val newArray = Array(IntFoo(10), IntFoo(20), IntFoo(30))
    SetArrayWithReflection(my, newArray)
    my.subs.foreach(f => println(f))
  }
}
```

The output I'm getting is:

```
would need to downcast from class java.lang.Object to class Foo
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at Main$.SetArrayWithReflection(Main.scala:19)
    at Main$.main(Main.scala:27)
    at Main.main(Main.scala)
```

Via reflection, I try to call a method expecting an Array[Object] with an Array[Foo], which obviously has to fail.
My question is: How can I downcast or create a suitable Array for method invocation?
The same code does work for Lists, however. I suppose this is due to type erasure which does not happen on Arrays.

Thanks in advance,

Velines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't downcast an `Array[Object]` to `Array[Foo]`. The simplest way to create the array you need is

```
val arrayFoo = Array.ofDim[Foo](arrayA.length)
System.arraycopy(arrayA, 0, arrayFoo, 0, arrayA.length)
```

See [`System.arraycopy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29).